# AndroidでCordova暗号化プラグインとFileAPIが併用出来ない

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5, cordova

初投稿になります。

Monacaを使ってハイブリットアプリを作成しまして、iOS版は無事リリース出来たのですが、Android版で躓いています。
Monacaデバッガーでは正常動作するんですが、Androidでデバッグビルドして動作検証した際、エラーが多発するため、一個一個メソッドやプラグインの検証を重ねた結果、
https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file
こちらのプラグインと、
FILEAPIの、window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()を併用した際、エラーとなることが分かりました。

こちらのソースで検証しましたが、エラーの動作もなく、無反応という状態です。

```
<script>
    function test() {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(entry) {
            var nativePath = entry.toURL();
            alert('Native URI: ' + nativePath);
        }, onErrorLoadFs);
    }
    function onErrorLoadFs(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
</script>
<body>
      <ons-button onclick="test()">click</ons-button>
</body>
```

**file://** を **http://localhost/** に変換しているせいなのかと思い、色々指定を変えてみたのですが、自分の力では実行に至りませんでした。
どなたか解決方法や代用プラグイン等ご存じの方が居ましたが、教えて頂けないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

---

### 環境

Cordova 6.2.0
Cordova Android 5.1.1
FileAPI 4.3.3
CordovaCrypt 1.3.3

---

### 8/16　追記

対応が遅くなりました。
Monacaサポートへ数回問い合わせをした結果、

> 「cordova-plugin-crypt-file」プラグインが組み込まれた場合、
>   Androidビルド時に、他のCordovaプラグインが正常に組み込まれない等の 問題が発生いたします。
>
> 上記の事象の原因は、 「cordova-plugin-crypt-file」プラグインに設定されている ビルド時の処理によるものになります。
>
> そのため、cordova-plugin-crypt-fileプラグインにつきましては、 Monacaではご利用になれません。

このような回答を頂きました。
iosでは正常に稼働しているため、悔しいです。
他に同様のプラグインをご存知のかたいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

Comment: エラーの詳細など追記できますでしょうか？[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)についてもご一読ください。

Comment: 検証したソースコードを追加いたしました。エラーハンドルが動作せず、エラーの詳細も掴めない状態です。

Comment: cordovaの場合、javascriptのalert関数は期待通り動作しなかったように記憶してます。cordovaのダイアログ機能(plugin)でエラー内容を出力させてみてはどうでしょうか?

Comment: cordova-plugin-dialogsであっているでしょうか？使ってみましたが、やはりエラーは表示されませんでした。Monacaデバッガーでは正しく表示されるため、ビルド時に暗号化したことが原因だと考えています。

Comment: 適当にCordovaプロジェクトを作成し、2つのプラグインをインストールし、`cordova build android`で検証ソースを試して見ましたが、特に問題なく`Native URI:`のアラートが表示されました。現状の提示されている情報だけでは問題の特定や解決が困難だと思います。問題が発生している環境の詳細な各バージョン情報や、可能であれば問題が再現する環境全体について追記できますでしょうか？`「file:// を http://localhost/ に変換している」`というのも通常はそんなことをする必要はないはずなので、気になります。

Comment: Cordova 6.2.0、Cordova Android 5.1.1、FileAPIE 4.3.3、CordovaCrypt 1.3.3 他に提示したほうが良い環境はありますでしょうか。file:///変換はCordovaCryptプラグインの仕様となります。Monacaのデバッグビルドだから動かないとか・・・は関係あるのでしょうか。

Comment: @L1010 提示いただいた環境(Cordova Android 5.1.1、[cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) 4.3.3、[cordova-plugin-crypt-file](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file) 1.3.3)で再度検証ソースを試してみましたが、`Native URI:`のアラートが表示されました。質問文中に出てきていない情報に原因がありそうです。Monacaが原因の可能性もあるので、Monacaのサポートに問い合わせた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: 念のための確認ですが検証ソースの`test()`は正常にコールされていますでしょうか？

Comment: test()は正常にコールされております。Monaca独特の仕様である可能性もありますので、問い合わせてみます。（Monacaで試された方で正常動作された方いらっしゃるのでしょうか）

Comment: 公式からの回答を追記しました。過去事例より使用できないことが分かりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ようやく解決方法を見つけたため、新規コメントにて記載させて頂きます。
（xmlを勉強していた為、遅くなりました。申し訳ありません）
まず、cryptプラグインはMonacaとは相性が悪いため、通常使用では駄目でした。
そこで、FILEAPIを暗号化の対象からはずして見たところ、上手く動作しました。

cryptプラグイン内、plugin.xmlを、以下の通り修正しました。
（ただし、本来提供されている形から外れてしまうため、ご了承下さい）

```
<cryptfiles>
    <include>
        <file regex="\.(htm|html|css|js)$" />
    </include>
    <exclude>
        <file regex="cordova\.js" />  ←追加
        <file regex="plugins" />      ←追加
    </exclude> 
</cryptfiles>
```

除外に「plugin」を含むファイルを追加。fileapi関係を一挙追加でも可能だと思いますが、プラグインには個人情報等を含んでいませんので、一括でpluginとしました。
更に、[cordova.js]も追加しています。
こちらは勉強不足でして、上記pluginだけでは動作しなかった為、ローラー作戦でjsファイルを一つずつ潰していった結果、こちらも追加しないと動作しないことが分かりました。

以上がこちらが対策した内容となります。
コメント頂いた皆様、ありがとうございました。